# How to share my AWS EC2 Reserved instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I want to know Is there any possibilities for sharing my Ec2 Reserved instance to some one or my another account.

Comment: Can you explain it some more?

Comment: When you purchase reserved instance, until reaching reserved instance criteria your reserved instance will be kept in idle state. So  you can share your reserved instance which are in idle state to another AWS accounts without making it public.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible and automatic provided the other account rolls up to the same consolidated billing account (and contains an instance of the same type, region, etc. as the reserved instance of course).

From AWS:

> The pricing benefits of Reserved Instances are shared when the
>   purchasing account is part of a set of accounts billed under one
>   consolidated billing (CB) payer account.

Source/further detail: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/concepts-reserved-instances-billing.html